# Asp.net Core 3.1, using Ajax to display json data on view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

*I wanna load data from the GetPatient Function the labels on the view for create. this is what i have so far, it is getting the data by id, but not returing it as json or showing on said labels. How do i fix this?*

```
 // GET: Appointments/Create
        public IActionResult Create(int id = 0)
        {
            if (id == 0)
                return View(new Appointments());
            else
                return View(_context.Appointments.Find(id));

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetPatient(int id = 0)
        {
            var Pt = _context.Mstr_Patients.Find(id);
            return Json(Pt);
        }
-------- Create View------------
<script>
            function GetPatient() {
            var url = "@Url.Action("GetPatient")";
            var id = $("#PID").val();
            $.get(url, { id: id }, function (data) {
                $("#PID").html(data.PatientID);
            });
        }
        $("#btnSearch").on("click", GetPatient);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any issues in your code, it should work fine. When you say "but not returning it as json", what it actually returns? have you checked in browser developer console?

Comment: @Roman.Pavelko how do i do that? I'm new to this!

Comment: If you are using Chrome, press F12, go to Network tab, select XHR tab, click your button on the view and check "GetPatient" result that appeared in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetPatient(int id = 0)
{
     if (id == 0)
     {
         return View(new Appointments());
     } 
     else
     {
         var patient = _context.Mstr_Patients.Find(id);

         if(patient == null)
         { 
             return StatusCode(404);
         } 

         var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patient);

         //This will make your content-type as JSON.
         return Content(serialized, "application/json");
      }   
}
```

And in your **View:**

```
<script>

    function GetPatient(){
       var PID = document.getElementById("#PID");  
       var id = PID.val();
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",            
            url: "@Url.Action("GetPatient")";
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"id": id}
            success: function (data) {
                $("#PID").html(data.PatientID);
            }
     }

     var btnSearch = document.getElementById("#btnSearch");

     btnSearch.onclick = () => {
            GetPatient();
     }

</script>
```

**Note:** I'm not 100% sure but in your AJAX call, you might need to change:
`data: {"id": id}` to `data: {id: id}`

Comment: tried this, script is not calling the Getpaient function, idk why. is there any syntax error on the script? i cant seem to figure it out. Nothing happens on the button click.

Comment: I've change the onclick function above, could you please try this? You should debug this one, I mean is the error about "onclick" function or "ajax" call